# Automated cross browser compatibility testing using image difference

Tags: testing, web, cross-browser, imagemagick, automated-tests

I am looking for a technique to spot differences in a web page across different browsers by comparing their screenshots. I need this as I am trying to automate our sites sanity check just as a tester would manually spot misplaced elements on the screen.

I have gone through the other threads which are similar yet do not answer my question. I have tried using tools such as imagemagick and PerceptualDiff which seemed to give me some inconsistent results when comparing two cross browser screenshots for similarity.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the options. I was aware of these issues but this was a requirement. Interesting alternatives though. :)

Comment: You are most welcome!  Have you looked at [Acid3](http://acid3.acidtests.org/reference.html) yet?  Or, [SuperPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/gg193004.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a whole bunch of looking for visual differences, I came to a conclusion. Even if this could be achieved with a good level of accuracy, it would still give rise to a lot of false positives as far as web site testing is concerned.

I would suggest that you use a programmatic approach to check web page once it has loaded.

Thank you so much for the help Brian.

Answer (score 0):

I have also done a lot of research in this area. For image based testing check out the following great articles:

http://kodu.ut.ee/~dumas/pubs/icsm2013Browserbite.pdf

http://kodu.ut.ee/~dumas/pubs/icwe2014browserbite.pdf

They are actually using this technique and have developed a commercial tool. Thee complete technique is based on Image Processing + Machine Learning.